# Use Open Sans Light as a default font in moderncv

Tags: fonts, moderncv

So I figured out that you can use Open Sans in any generic LaTeX document by adding the following lines:

```
\usepackage[default,scale=0.9]{opensans}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Now, what I want to do is instead use the lighter variant of the font, Open Sans Light as the default throughout my document. How do I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use it with the generic font switching commands (`\usefont{T1}{fos}{l}{n}`, &c.) but it's simpler to define shortcuts. I give them for the non standard weights (`light`, `light-condensed`, `semibold` and `extrabold`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[defaultsans]{opensans}

\DeclareRobustCommand\ebseries{\fontseries{eb}\selectfont}
\DeclareRobustCommand\sbseries{\fontseries{sb}\selectfont}
\DeclareRobustCommand\ltseries{\fontseries{l}\selectfont}
\DeclareRobustCommand\clseries{\fontseries{cl}\selectfont}

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\texteb}{\ebseries}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsb}{\sbseries}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textlt}{\ltseries}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textcl}{\clseries}

    \begin{document}

\sffamily

{\ebseries
This line is extrabold \textsc{text text text text}.}

{\sbseries
This line is semibold \textsc{text text text text}.}

A normal text \textsc{text text text text}.


\textcl{A condensed light text.}

\ltseries
A light text text text text

\textsc{A light smallcaps text}

\itshape A light italic text

\scshape A light small caps italic text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although not op, thank you. If you were to use different text for each line, the differences would be way faster to spot. :)

Comment: @henry: You're right, all the more so as an image doesn't have the details that a .pdf has. I'll change that at once. Btw, what does ‘not op’ mean (I'm not a native speaker)?

Comment: Thanks! Not a native speaker neither, but AFAIK *op* is used to refer either to the **o** pening **p** oster or simply the **o** pening **p** ost.

Comment: Is there a way to set the thin variant as the default font for all the continuous text in the document, and maybe the captions?

Answer (score 4):

Use `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex` then you can easily define all font faces:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[%  
  BoldFont      =Open Sans Bold,
  ItalicFont    =Open Sans Italic,
  BoldItalicFont=Open Sans Bold Italic]{Open Sans Regular}
\newfontfamily\light[%
  BoldFont      =Open Sans Semibold,
  ItalicFont    =Open Sans Light Italic,
  BoldItalicFont=Open Sans Semibold Italic]{Open Sans Light}
\newfontfamily\condlight[%
  ItalicFont    =Open Sans Cond Light Italic]{Open Sans Cond Light}
\begin{document}
text text text text\par
{\bfseries Text text text text}\par
{\itshape Text text text text}\par
{\itshape\bfseries text text text text}

\light
text text text text\par
{\bfseries Text text text text}\par
{\itshape Text text text text}\par
{\itshape\bfseries text text text text}

\condlight
text text text text\par
{\itshape Text text text text}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does it still work if you change the document class from `article` to `moderncv`?

Comment: it depends to `moderncv` if it defines fonts itself. In general it should work.

Comment: The question was specifically about `moderncv`, so it might help to test your answer with that document class...